# laravel get function empty data

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm using angularjs with laravel in my project.

I'm trying to get items from a table. 642 rows. On my localhost, the browser returns the items in the html table  but on the server, it returns an empty data.

Any help ? (same code localhost-server)

Comment: Are you sure its the same database?

Comment: Also, read your question back and pretend you are one of us. Would you be able to help you, given the information you have provided us with?????

Comment: I'm sorry for this. I was checking the problem, while using xampp, after executing the function it returns all the 642 rows. But on the server, the get function returns only 100 rows, not more.

Comment: @ElioChamy could you also add your code here. I hope that both database you are connecting to is the same or atleast has the same contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved my problem, it was the max memory in the php.ini (16M) we could put it  to 128M, but I don't know how many items we will add later on
So I used laravel pagination with bootpag js plugin, and now I get in every page (1,2,3 ..etc) 15 items using ->paginate() in my laravel query.